# Stacked clustered percentage bar with labels

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have the following multiIndexed dataframe

```
data_json="""{"Group":{"0":"G1","1":"G1","2":"G2","3":"G2","4":"G3","5":"G3"},
            "Letter":{"0":"A","1":"B","2":"A","3":"B","4":"A","5":"B"},
            "Percentage":{"0":0.5,"1":0.2,"2":0.3,"3":0.5,"4":0.7,"5":0.7},
            "1-Percentage":{"0":0.5,"1":0.8,"2":0.7,"3":0.5,"4":0.3,"5":0.3}}"""

df=pd.read_json(data_json).set_index(['Group','Letter'])
df
Out[152]: 
              Percentage  1-Percentage
Group Letter                          
G1    A              0.5           0.5
      B              0.2           0.8
G2    A              0.3           0.7
      B              0.5           0.5
G3    A              0.7           0.3
      B              0.7           0.3
```

Output in json:

**Is there a way to reproduce the following graph?**

[image]

So far i have managed only managed to get the stacked graph but still dont now how to show the Multilevel on the x-axis, nor can i add the labels to the bars, this is code and result so far:

```
plotdata=plotdata*100

plotdata.plot(kind='bar',stacked=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this bit of code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import groupby

d = {'Percentage': {('G1', 'A'): 50.0,
  ('G1', 'B'): 20.0,
  ('G2', 'A'): 30.0,
  ('G2', 'B'): 50.0,
  ('G3', 'A'): 70.0,
  ('G3', 'B'): 70.0},
 '1-Percentage': {('G1', 'A'): 50.0,
  ('G1', 'B'): 80.0,
  ('G2', 'A'): 70.0,
  ('G2', 'B'): 50.0,
  ('G3', 'A'): 30.0,
  ('G3', 'B'): 30.0}}

plotdata = pd.DataFrame(d)

def add_line(ax, xpos, ypos):
    line = plt.Line2D([xpos, xpos], [ypos + .1, ypos],
                      transform=ax.transAxes, color='gray')
    line.set_clip_on(False)
    ax.add_line(line)

def label_len(my_index,level):
    labels = my_index.get_level_values(level)
    return [(k, sum(1 for i in g)) for k,g in groupby(labels)]

def label_group_bar_table(ax, df):
    ypos = -.1
    scale = 1./df.index.size
    for level in range(df.index.nlevels)[::-1]:
        pos = 0
        for label, rpos in label_len(df.index,level):
            lxpos = (pos + .5 * rpos)*scale
            ax.text(lxpos, ypos, label, ha='center', transform=ax.transAxes)
            add_line(ax, pos*scale, ypos)
            pos += rpos
        add_line(ax, pos*scale , ypos)
        ypos -= .1

ax = plotdata.plot(kind='bar',stacked=True)
ax.set_xticklabels('')
ax.set_xlabel('')
label_group_bar_table(ax, plotdata)
```

<strike>for rec, label in zip(ax.patches,plotdata['Percentage'].round(0).astype(int).astype(str)+'%'):

height = rec.get_height()

ax.text(rec.get_x() + rec.get_width() / 2, height / 2, label,

ha = 'center', va='bottom', color='w')</strike>

```
#Update using matplotlib 3.4.2

for c in ax.containers[::2]:
    ax.bar_label(c, label_type='center', fmt='%0.0f%%', padding=10, color='w')
```

Output chart:

[image]

Comment: @AndrésBraga Did this solution help you?